# Convert a dictionary to accessible array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, blender

How can I convert the following dictionary which contains an array within an array: to an array easily so I can access for example array[0]

```
{'New Beton': [`'C:\\User\\New map\\Test1.jpg',`'C:\\User\\New map\\Test2.jpg', 'C:\\User\\New map\\Test3.jpg']}
```

Which I need to convert to

```
New Beton = ["C:\\User\\New map\\Test1.jpg", "C:\\User\\New map\\Test2.jpg", "C:\\User\\New map\\Test3.jpg"]
```

Comment: Where is the array within the array? Try ```new_benton = new_benton["New Beton"]```

Comment: Those are lists not arrays.

Comment: Python does not allow spaces in variable names.
You can already access your dictionary list by using `New_Beton['New Beton'][0]` for the first element.
But if you want to keep the list only, you can use `New_Beton = New_Beton['New Beton']`. And after calling `New_Beton[0]` as you requested.

Comment: Maybe use https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access it directly.

```
you_dict['New Beton'][0]
```

And make sure your variable names don't have whitespace. I think except 'Rockstar' no language allows that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to convert dictionary into  a nested list? Then, something like this will work.

```py
def convert(d):
    l = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        l.append(v)
    return l

d = {'foo':['bar', 'baz']}
l = convert(d)
print(l[0])
```

but there are better ways to get that value without creating a list. it'd ve great if you could share more details about what you want to do so that i can give you specific examples.

Comment: oh did you want to define a variable with the string value? then `exac()` can be what you're looking for.